# How to get the position of the currently focussed input?

Tags: react-native

I need to know the position of the currently focussed input to make some calculations. At the end I want to call `.measure()` on it.

What I got:

```
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

const { State: TextInputState } = TextInput;
var currentlyFocussedField      = TextInputState.currentlyFocusedField();

console.log('currentlyFocussedField', currentlyFocussedField);
```

But this only returns the id of the text field (like `394`, and the next field is `395`). How can I access the real element/object or how do I get its position on the screen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know how you can access the React component from the numeric `reactTag` in javascript, but you can use the same `UIManager.measure(reactTag, callback)` function that RN uses internally to make `.measure()` work.

It's not documented, but you can find the source [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Modules/RCTUIManager.m), for iOS, and [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/uimanager/UIManagerModule.java) for Android.

You can use this to get the all the size values of the native view.  For example, drawing from your example above:

```
import { UIManager, TextInput } from 'react-native';

const { State: TextInputState } = TextInput;
const currentlyFocusedField = TextInputState.currentlyFocusedField();

UIManager.measure(currentlyFocusedField, (originX, originY, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
  console.log(originX, originY, width, height, pageX, pageY);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I'm getting the position of a focused input to scroll to it:

```
import { findNodeHandle, ScrollView, TextInput, UIManager } from 'react-native'

class SomeForm extends Component {
  scrollTo (element) {
    const handle = findNodeHandle(this[element])
    if (handle) {
      UIManager.measure(handle, (x, y) => {
        this._scrollView.scrollTo({
          animated: true,
          y
        })
      })
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <ScrollView
        ref={(element) => {
          this._scrollView = element
        }}
      >
        <TextInput
          onFocus={() => this.scrollTo('_inputName')}
          ref={(element) => {
            this._inputName = element
          }}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

`var currentlyFocussedField      = TextInputState.currentlyFocusedField();`

use:

`var currentlyFocussedField      = TextInputState.currentlyFocusedInput();`

Then you can:

`currentlyFocussedField.measure(...)`